# Local time for reflected random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes

Say I have a process starting from 0, and last for 100 steps, each step either moves up or down by one unit, within the boundary -10 and 10.

My understanding is that since this is a martingale, the expected hitting time would be 100, but how to calculate the local time aka how many times it would hit the boundaries within the 100 steps?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just creating the proper probability sum (exactly 10 + exactly 11 +... where the number signifies the boundary hitting) for up (X2 and you add the down) and than multiply it by 100 - the number of attempts.